# how would linux perform in a virtural box as compared to a fresh installation?

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox

My plan on a new laptop is to create a host windows 7 system and isolate a drive to install a virtual box containing a linux system on it. My concerns are

(1) would the linux system perform nearly identically as a freshly install linux as far as its functionality is concerned? How about their running speed?

(2) Would the linux in a virtual box access windows partition equally well as in the case of dual booting partition? Let's both linux and windows use fat32 file system. I plan to access

(3) which linux system you might suggest to be installed in the virtual box?

Comment: would it be a good idea to debug code (with relatively big i/o to disk) using a guest os installed within a virtual box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Functionality, yes for the basics (CPU/Disk/display). Things get more complicated when it comes to 3D video, network interfaces and USB (which the VM doesn't really see), but in practice it seldom matters.. In theory disk access in slower, in practice unless the VM runs I/O bound programs you won't  notice a difference.

2) Normally you use shared folders. No need for partitions.

3) Depends a lot on what you want to do. It's a VM, so the smaller the better. If you want to have the feel of a full Linux UI you will have to install a "regular" distro (Ubuntu, Mint, Fedora) but if it is to run things like servers there are more [lightweight distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Linux_distribution).

Comment: Thanks, this is quite reassuring that linux in a virtualbox will not be noticeably slower than a hardware installation. I will give it a try to see how fast it actually is.

Comment: Towards installation, I guess your answer is based on the assumption that linux takes a file system which is recognized by both linux and windows in order for file sharing, is it? If linux is installed under FAT32, then any file on that that FAT32 partition should be equally well accessible by linux within the virtualbox and the windows host os, and there is nothing I need to worry about it, is my understanding correct?

Comment: The main purpose of a linux subsystem is to work, so I basically need linux script, c++, fortran, python, together with necessary utility software like mathematica, matlab, gnuplot, x11 etc, and active support on drivers and software update. Given these requirement, what lightweight linux distribution is recommended?  The links come with too many choices which is timidating to me.

Comment: Does the clipboard and copy and paste functionality supported between the host windows os and the linux subsystem within the virtualbox?

Comment: Distro: I would recommend one of the Ubuntu derivatives (Lubuntu/Xubuntu) as being quite beginner-friendly. Clipboard: it works well for me (but I run a Win VM in a Linux host, so I don't know how that applies to you).

Answer (score 1):

1. Linux installed on hardware and in a VM will be identical.  The installation is exactly the same.  There is no need to isolate a drive, as VirtualBox creates a *file* to act as a virtual hard disk.  It is possible to use a real disk, but  thats more [advanced](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html).  As for speed, Windows will be slower, as the VM will be using resources.  And the Linux VM will be slower than a hardware install, as it doesnt have all the resources and it has to pass IO to the host machine.
2. The Linux VM will be abstracted from the host OSs hard drive.  There are multiple methods to access the host machine, such as VB shared folders, and Windows shares.
3. This is purely opinion.  Any Linux distro can be installed in a VM, as long as the architectures are compatible.

Answer (score -1):

A quick [google search](https://www.google.de/search?q=performance+VM+vs+native) will already answer most of those questions. If you want linux to access your windows partitions you need to share those drives over the virtual network because linux won't be able to access them directly.

I would suggest a beginner friendly linux distibution like Linux Mint or Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want the guest os to access windows partition, but all files and guest os will be on the same drive with FAT32 file system. I guess this should pose no issue for mutual access, is it? Would the two recommended os, Linux Mint and Ubuntu, be too big for me? I would roughly allocate 20G for setting up the guest os including necessary software to run under linux.